# How to use a crontab to edit variables within a PHP file?

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible to edit variables from a PHP file with the use of Cronjob? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Basically I have a PHP file that looks like this:

```
<?php
$daynumber = "1";
$txid = tx1;
$endtime = "2014-3-28 20:30:00 GMT+11:00";
?>
```

What I want is that every 24 hours it changes it by increasing the day number by one and the txid by one.

So basicaly after the cron job running 24 hours after the code above it will look like this:

```
<?php
$daynumber = "2";
$txid = tx2;
$endtime = "2014-3-29 20:30:00 GMT+11:00";
?>
```

Is it possible to do? If not, what other way could I produce the same result.

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help I receive.

Comment: normally you would set a value in a database and the php script will read that value.

Comment: Life is surprising - I would never expect that someone wants to alter the source code from cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forget about cron for this task**
Even without the database - if for some reason you don't want to use it:

```
<?php
define("FIRST_DAY_STRING", "2014-3-26");
define("SHIFT_DAYS", 'P2D');
define("TIME_SUFFIX", " 20:30:00 GMT+11:00");

$today = new DateTime();
$first_day = new DateTime(FIRST_DAY_STRING);
$interval = $first_day->diff($today);
$days = $interval->format('%R%a days');
$end_date = $today->add(new DateInterval(SHIFT_DAYS));

$day_number = intval($days) + 1;
$txid = "tx$day_number";
$end_time = $end_date->format('Y-n-j')
$end_time .= TIME_SUFFIX
?>
```

This example assumes that you start counting days from 2014-3-26 (day 1) and the endtime is always 2 days later at 20:30:00. You can alter the constants to get a different behavior.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your detailed answer. How would you recommend going about using MYSQL for this task?

Comment: MySQL is also ok. Far better than this idea with cron :) Please upvote and/or accept my answer if you think it's ok. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I have accepted your answer. Since I a quite a "noob" to PHP and MYSQL would it be alright for me to open another question on StackOverflow which asks for the solution to my problem but utilizing MYSQL rather than CRON? Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for giving an alternative to that cron-editing! :) good so!

Comment: @user3462992 yes, feel free to ask about MySQL solution. Describe what is the purpose of this code. But one important thing. Write a short code sample - how would you approach the problem. Probably there will be a lot of bugs, but SO members appreciate the fact that you have a concept. Don't ask for a ready made solution! You had an idea to alter the code with cron. Even if it was a bad idea, that was the reason I've written my answer for. You have to prove that you really try to solve the problem on SO. Then you get help from us.

Comment: Hey, just another question. If I wanted to edit it to make it on a weekly or monthly basis how could I go about that?

Is this all I have to change?:
define("SHIFT_DAYS", 'P7D');

Comment: Hey Elmo, can you please assist me in answering this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888967/make-a-timer-reset-every-30-days

I really would appreciate it!