# Make a timer reset every 30 days?

Tags: php

I currently have code that changes the month number and MYSQL table every month automatically but the timer it displays still resets every 24 hours. I need to make it so the timer resets every month instead of every 24 hours. I am not thinking straight and need some help solving this.

Basically I need it so that $month_end_time counts down from 30 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes 0 seconds down to 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes 0 seconds and then resets back to the 30 days. Currently it counts down from 30 days to 29 days then resets as it is from a script that resets every 24 hours and I am porting it to monthly.

Credits to @ElmoVanKielmo for the original snippet.

Thanks in advance.

```
define("FIRST_DAY_STRING", "2014-4-6");
define("SHIFT_DAYS", 'P30D');
define("TIME_SUFFIX", " 0:00:00 GMT+11:00");

$today = new DateTime();
$first_day = new DateTime(FIRST_DAY_STRING);
$interval = $first_day->diff($today);
$days = $interval->format('%R%a days');
$end_date = $today->add(new DateInterval(SHIFT_DAYS));

$month_number = floor(intval($days) / 30 + 1);
$txid = "tx$month_number";
$month_end_time = $end_date->format('Y-n-j');
$month_end_time .= TIME_SUFFIX;
```

Comment: but not every month has 30 days...

Comment: I realise that, it's not the aim to replicate the months, its just a 30 day timer for a function on my site.

Comment: Why don't you get the number of days between your start date and today and divide by 30? http://codepad.viper-7.com/KBVfqq

Comment: Whenever I try to divide $interval I get errors.

Comment: what is the error you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're possibly overthinking this, since it includes "dates". When moving around months, it can be tricky, since (as Raptor notes), months have differing number of days between each other.

However, based on your comments, you're actually looking for the number of *30-day periods* between one date and another. This can be accomplished with basic math and Unix timestamps:

```
$start = strtotime('2012-04-12 00:00:00 GMT');
$today = strtotime('00:00:00 GMT');
$days = ($today - $start) / 60 / 60 / 24;
$months = $days / 30;

echo "<pre>
Days: $days
Months: $months
";
```

This will give:

```
Days: 723
Months: 24.1
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/KBVfqq

And if you're trying to figure out how many days:

```
$start = strtotime('2012-04-12 00:00:00 GMT');
$today = strtotime('00:00:00 GMT');
$days = ($today - $start) / 60 / 60 / 24;
$months = $days / 30;
$months_days = floor($months) . " months, " . ($days - (floor($months) * 30)) . " days";

echo "<pre>
Days: $days
Months: $months
Months and Days: $months_days
";
```

Giving:

```
Days: 723
Months: 24.1
Months and Days: 24 months, 3 days
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/AdnFsu

Which means that between the start and today's date, there have been 24 full 30-day periods, and we are currently in the 25th period (`ceil($months)`). This seems sufficient for what you are after, although the specific use of the period value may require better explanation.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. However, I already have the function that gets what month it is after the day, I only need for the timer to count down from 30 days to 0 days instead of only counting down from 30 days to 29 days. I am using this as the timer code: http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/countdown/

Thanks.

Comment: Your distinction isn't quite making sense to me. If you want to know what (number of) day to initialize the countdown to, take the last part of `$month_days` and subtract that from 30, e.g., `$countdown_day = 30 - ($days - (floor($months) * 30));`. In the case I have above, that would show the days as being `27 days remaining` for the given 30-day period.

Comment: Basically I just need $month_end_time to equal 30 days after $first_day and then when that 30 days is over make $month_end_time equal 30 days after then last end date. So every 30 days the timer resets. Is that possible?

Comment: If, on the hand (...), you need the actual dates to initialize as the beginning/end of the countdown period (beginning April 2, ending May 2 for a 30 day period), that can be done as well by getting the number of days in the number of months minus the remainder (e.g., 24), then add 30 days (e.g., `strtotime('+30 days', $period)`. That would give you two unix timestamps with a given 30-day period representing even number of 30-day periods since the first period began.

Comment: Ok. To be honest with you, I'm quite a beginner at PHP and coding in general. It would help me immensely if you could edit the code in my question so the variables all stay the same and stay in context so it does what I need it to do. In return for you doing this I can tip you some Bitcoin, if you choose to accept please leave your Bitcoin address for me to send you some BTC to say thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I don't do Bitcoin, but I appreciate the offer. It's pretty late here too, so I'm probably too tired to think about it. I'll take a fresh look tomorrow morning and see if I can make better sense of it. One question: Is the `FIRST_DAY_STRING` a fixed date, so you need to detect when you roll over and "reset" `FIRST_DAY_STRING` to the beginning of the (current, today's) period? This is what's throwing me, I think.

Comment: This is the original question from which I got the code: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654363/how-to-use-a-crontab-to-edit-variables-within-a-php-file) 

define("FIRST_DAY_STRING", "2014-4-6"); is the day which the system starts. define("TIME_SUFFIX", " 0:00:00 GMT+11:00"); is the time in which it started and which it will end 30 days later. So basically, 

2014-5-6 0:00:00 GMT+11:00 is the whole string on which the timer is counting down to which is based on the [COUNTDOWN](http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/countdown/) snippet I'm using.

Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/sK9VrQ This will correct for the *current* period using the number of `SHIFT_DAYS + 1` (you seem to be including the zero-day, so it's really 31 days). So this will (should) automatically restart the countdown on the 32nd day of a period, back to 30. Also notice that `$current_period == $month_number`, as it should, even though both are calculated differently. I show the `$month_start_time` as well for validation purposes.

Comment: Actually, I think I need to increment the next period by `1`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bLi6cV

Comment: Ok thank you very much, that works! Now I would assume that I could also make this weekly instead of monthly as well, correct? Thanks again,

Comment: If you change the shift days constant to `7`, it should work the same.

Comment: The original comment three comments above (not the "corrected" comment) is right; I forgot about the GMT+11:00, so this morning I was seeing yesterday (instead of today), since the server I believe is at GMT-8:00.